# How to maintain 6 months bank statements for UK visit visa?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-employment

I am a doctor and I want to give my plab 2 exam in the UK.  As I am a recent graduate my father is supporting me financially. He is a retired government officer who gets pension, rents from his properties and interest from his fixed term deposits. Please tell me that how should I maintain his bank statement for 6 months, and is my employment necessary to get a visit visa as I heard from many guys that it shows ties back to your country.

Comment: What do you mean by 'maintain' his accounts?

Comment: I meant that how the transactions should be made that will satisfy the clearance officer , like on a monthly basis how the amount should be deposited and how should it be with drawn. In other words how to maintain a healthy statement. And while depositing which one is better a cheque or cash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are relying on your father's sponsorship to get an entry clearance for your PLAB, you should get the most recent 3 - 6 months of his bank statements.  These should be accompanied by a letter prepared by your father that explains each and every movement through the account and establishes the provenance of his funds.  Provenance of funds is a very popular refusal reason at the moment.

Your evidence (including your father's explanation) should be translated.

If you want to play it strictly by the book, the bank statements should be originals provided by the bank or taken to the bank and be authenticated as genuine by the cognizant bank officer.

For your other question, they already know that PLAB applicants are just starting out in life and may not have impressive employment credentials.  You can compensate for this by demonstrating that you have great offers on the table or something else that shows promise.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My question is that how a healthy 6 month statement should look like in my father's current situation. Like how should he handle the account and how the transactions should be made that would satisfy the clearance officer. And please also tell me that which transaction is better , one made by the cheque or cash?

Comment: @ahmed, they don't have a concept for 'healthy' in that context. Bank statements should look like a normal person leading a normal life doing normal things that are transparent and legal.  They see lots of bank statements that are variously different and they only question a small minority of them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please also help me with another issue i started a job at a private hospital and the salary they pay to me is in the form of cash. So , while showing my employment i can provide them with the letter by my hospital stating that i work there , my position , salary etc but i can't provide them with my bank statement. Is that going to be a problem and reason for refusal?